# How do I get an alphanumeric / alphaid (base 62) youtube-like id string from an integer column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I convert an id INT column in MySQL to a base 62 alphanumeric string?

Basically I really need a MySQL implementation of the following:

http://kvz.io/blog/2009/06/10/create-short-ids-with-php-like-youtube-or-tinyurl/

Comment: By your rep, you seem to be a solid SO member. Surely, you know StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We are volunteer programmers here to help troubleshoot earnest efforts.

Comment: I may answer my own question at some point.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do this for larger-than-INT binary data (base-256 UUIDs specifically), so I created this stored function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION base62(x VARBINARY(16)) RETURNS VARCHAR(22) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE digits CHAR(62) DEFAULT "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  DECLARE n NUMERIC(39) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(22) DEFAULT "";
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE i <= LENGTH(x) DO
    SET n = n * 256 + ORD(SUBSTR(x, i, 1));
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
  WHILE n > 0 DO
    SET s = CONCAT(SUBSTR(digits, (n MOD 62) + 1, 1), s);
    SET n = FLOOR(n / 62);
  END WHILE;
  RETURN s;
END//
```

You can remove the first loop if you've already got a numeric type. You may also wish to adjust the alphabet; for instance, the base-64 puts letters before numbers.

Comment: efficient base62 to int ?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to generate id using uuid or use auto increment to store in mysql but encode decode it while using it for front end. You can use this library to generate non sequential unique id's from numbers.

http://hashids.org

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this MySQL function successfully. It takes a BIGINT parameter as input and returns BASE62 Youtube style ID's.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `i2s`(
`_n` BIGINT
)
RETURNS tinytext CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

declare d char(62) default '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
declare s tinytext default '0';
declare i int default 1;

if _n>0 then set s=''; end if;

while _n > 0 do
    set s = concat(substr(d, (_n mod 62) + 1, 1),s);
    set _n = floor(_n / 62);
end while;

return s;

END
```